# Android: Using default styles

Tags: android, styles, themes

```
<style name="test" parent="@android:style/WindowTitle"></style>
```

Whenever I type the above, I get the following error message from eclipse:

```
Description
Resource Path Location Type

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/WindowTitle'.
styles.xml  /alertdialogapp/res/values  line 3  Android AAPT Problem
```

The same error also appears when I use the style `@android:style/AlertDialog`

Answer (score 2):

`WindowTitle` and `AlertDialog` are private styles in the platform and you cannot reference them.

Some ancient versions of aapt had a bug which allowed you to reference private styles but it's been fixed a long time ago. Private style resource identifiers are not guaranteed to stay the same across platform builds, so even if you managed to dig up the resource identifier somewhere, it would likely break at some point.

If you need to extend a particular private platform theme, copy the style definitions you need from [platform sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) to your own project.

Comment: What do you mean by copying the definition from platform resources?