# Using Private Styles in Android

Tags: android, styles, themes

Okay this is the third time I am asking this question. It would be appreciative if someone gave me a concrete answer with an appropriate example..

While styling my `Android UI`, I needed to change the look and feel of my `ALertDialog`. However, I tried import the alert dialog default style using the following

```
style name="alertDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog"
```

While doing the above I get an error saying something like "parent resource not found". As far as I heard from others it seems that its a private style and cannot be used.

So is there anyway that it can be used that I am nit aware of?

Comment: Isn't "If you need to extend a particular private platform theme, copy the style definitions you need from platform sources to your own project" concrete enough. From my answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298006/android-using-default-styles . Anyway, instead of re-posting essentially the same question, please edit the older one to contain the additional information.

Comment: Even if you copy the style definitions it still doesn't work...Say I copy the AlertDialog style..it says it cannot recognize the item names

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to use a **Theme** as your parent instead of a Style.

For AlertDialog, the default theme is `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.Alert` for Honeycomb and later, and `@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert` for older versions.

You can see the theme declaration in [ANDROID_SDK]/platforms/android-19/data/res/values/themes.xml. There are several variations you might be interested into.